# Get "lastModifiedDateTime" with MS Graph or REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph

I want to extract the "lastModifiedDateTime" from a list. I don't want to search the list by ID, but rather from its name. I know you can do it by MS graph, but the examples needs site ID as well as List ID. I want it in this similar form (tested in MS Graph explorer):

```
const SiteUrl = this.context.current.Web.Url;

SiteUrl+"/Lists/Project%20Information/AllItems.aspx/lastModifiedDateTime"
```

Does not work. Notice I want to use the current URL and hardcoded path (since all list have the same ending/name in the URL from provisioning, but the ID is different).

Is there any way I can use MS Graph to get the lastModifiedDateTime by site and list NAME and not ID? Or with Rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use SP API `_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('listName')` endpoint which returns list informations and deal with *LastItemDeletedDate* and *LastItemModifiedDate*.
Here's a working code:

```
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle(\'stuff\')';
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if(this.status == 200) {
            res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.d.LastItemModifiedDate);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Err. Could not return data.');
        }
    }
};

xhr.open('GET', requestUri, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
xhr.send();
```